# TextView doesn't show full text

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView which works normally, but if I try to show text more than 500-600 symbols it doesn't show them, it just cuts them. Also is pushing down these 2 buttons and they are hiding and not visible. This is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="13.07"
    android:background="@drawable/restaurants_buttons"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/name"
       android:layout_width="280dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingBottom="10dp"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:text="" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rest_id"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkMenues"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/checkMenues" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makeReservation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/makeReservation" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem textview is `android:id="@+id/text"`

Comment: the width is been restricted to android:layout_width="280dp"

Comment: Yes? Don't I need height? Width is for ..width?

Comment: try to double the size and watch the output

Comment: @d.i.v.a, this doesn't help me. I need `height` not `width`. Like this content goes somewhere on right and is hiden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the linear layout in a scroll layout.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="13.07"
            android:background="@drawable/restaurants_buttons"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rest_id"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/checkMenues"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="@string/checkMenues" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/makeReservation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="@string/makeReservation" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The App crash because `ScrollView can host only one child...`

Comment: I said to **wrap** your Linearlayout in a Scrollview. Not _replace_ the linearlayout with a scrollview. You currently have a LinearLayout as the root element which has two Linearlayout child elements. Wrap the _**root**_ LinearLayout in a ScrollView.

Comment: Yes, this is what I do. I put on root LinearLayout - ScrollView instead

Comment: I don't get it .. first time I've made it like this and gave me the error. Now is working. Thank you!